# Problems with wrapping Lua into a C++ class

Tags: c++, linux, class, lua, destructor

I'm using the [`Lua C API`](http://www.lua.org/download.html) in `C++` and I'm wrapping it into a class as follows:

```
class LuaScripting {
public:
    lua_State *lua;

    LuaScripting();

    ~LuaScripting();

    bool execute_script(const std::string &script);
};

LuaScripting::LuaScripting() {
    lua = luaL_newstate(); /* Opens Lua */
    luaL_openlibs(lua); /* Opens the standard libraries */

    /* Register our custom function(s) */
    lua_register(lua, "write8", lua_write8);
    lua_register(lua, "write16", lua_write16);
    lua_register(lua, "write32", lua_write32);
    lua_register(lua, "read8", lua_read8);
    lua_register(lua, "read16", lua_read16);
    lua_register(lua, "read32", lua_read32);
    lua_register(lua, "math_sin", math_sin);
}

LuaScripting::~LuaScripting() {
    lua_close(lua); /* Clean up lua */
}
```

I'm testing it as follows:

```
int main() {
    // Disable buffering
    setbuf(stdout, nullptr);

    LuaScripting lua_scripting;
    testWritingInt8(lua_scripting);
    testWritingInt16(lua_scripting);
    testWritingInt32(lua_scripting);
    testReadingInt32(lua_scripting);
    test_math_sin(lua_scripting);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problems I'm having:

- After the first `testWritingInt8()` the class destructor is called which will run `lua_close(lua)` even though the class instance didn't fall out of scope, yet. I'm not using any threads. Why is this happening?
- When calling `lua_close(lua)` the program crashes, why?
- After commenting out `lua_close(lua)` the write test cases run successfully but the `readXX()` or `math_sin()` return with an empty stack despite pushing a value onto the stack. Why?

Implementation:

```
static int math_sin(lua_State *lua) {
    const auto value = luaL_checknumber(lua, 1);
    const auto sine_result = sin(value);
    lua_pushnumber(lua, sine_result);
    return 1;
}
```

Test case:

```
void test_math_sin(LuaScripting &lua_scripting) {
    std::stringstream lua_script_builder;
    const auto target_value = 90.f;
    lua_script_builder << "math_sin(" << target_value << ")";
    const auto script_result = lua_scripting.execute_script(lua_script_builder.str());
    assert(script_result == LUA_OK);
    // TODO Not working
    const auto read_value = (int32_t) lua_tonumber(*lua_scripting.lua, -1);
    assert(target_value == read_value);
}
```

I'm always using the same `lua_State *` and I only call `luaL_newstate()` once.

As an attempted fix I tried to declare the lua state as a non-pointer:

```
lua_State lua; // error: aggregate ‘lua_State lua’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

But doing this does not compile.

Adding another level of indirection via `lua_State **lua` fixes the crashing problem with `lua_close()` but does not fix any of the other issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are copying the `LuaScripting` object. I bet `testWritingInt8` is declared like this:

```
void testWritingInt8(LuaScripting lua)
```

Notice the `lua` parameter is not a pointer or a reference to a LuaScripting object, it *is* a LuaScripting object.

So when you call `testWritingInt8(lua)`, the computer copies the LuaScripting object into a new one, calls the function, and destroys the new one at the end the call.

Now, why does that crash? Well, your `LuaScripting` class doesn't have a copy constructor (`LuaScripting(const LuaScripting &)`) so the compiler creates a default one, which just copies all the member variables - in this case the `lua` pointer is copied. Then, when the new object is destroyed, it frees the Lua state.

Solution: Make it so `LuaScripting` objects can't be copied accidentally, by deleting the copy constructor. Also the assignment operator.

```
// inside LuaScripting
LuaScripting(const LuaScripting &) = delete;
LuaScripting &operator =(const LuaScripting &) = delete;
```

Then make sure to pass `LuaScripting` values by reference.

If you want to be able to *move* `LuaScripting` objects around - say, if you want to store them in a vector, but still not copy them - you can define a *move constructor* and *move assignment operator*, which are out of scope of this answer.

---

Your `math_sin` test case doesn't return any values on the stack because... your script doesn't return any values. Try `return math_sin(target_value)` instead of just `math_sin(target_value)`.

Comment: Thanks, you were right. However, when I push to the lua stack, the changes are still lost after the call to `math_sin()` returns. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza If you have a problem with a test case maybe you should show people the code for the test case.

Comment: I added the test case now.

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza and I answered it.